# How can I remove proxies field in symfony json

Tags: json, symfony, jms-serializer

I want to remove proxies fields like `__initializer__: null,__cloner__: null, __isInitialized__: true,` from my returned json but I have no idea.

I dont want to use `* @Serializer\Exclude()` because there are some more fields next to those fields.

here is a sample json:

```
emails: [
    {
        id: 1,
        subject: "Mrs. Astrid Wuckert",
        body: "Excepturi.",
        sendCopy: false,
        roles: [
            {
                __initializer__: null,
                __cloner__: null,
                __isInitialized__: true,
                name: "ROLE_ADMIN"
            },
            {
                name: "ROLE_RESELLER"
            },
            {
                name: "ROLE_RETAILER"
            },
            {
                name: "ROLE_CLUB_SHOP"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does `$em->detach($object);` remove the proxy field?

Answer (score 0):

Try call ignoring fields while creating normalizer:

```
$normalilzer->setIgnoredAttributes(["__initializer__", "__cloner__","__isInitialized__"]);
```

Comment: What is `$normalilzer` ?